# libbpf: failed to find BTF for extern 'unlikely': -2

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, bpf, ebpf

I am trying to compile and run the `sockex3` example ([sockex3_user.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/samples/bpf/sockex3_user.c) and [sockex3_kern.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/samples/bpf/sockex3_kern.c) from v5.10) in a new project (out of the kernel tree) with [libbpf](https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf) v0.3 as submodule of my repository. I have compiled the code with the following flags:

kernel (ebpf program)

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER clang)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall -g -target bpf")
```

user

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER clang)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall -g")
```

clang

```
$ clang -v
clang version 11.0.0
```

So, when I run the binary, I have faced the following error:

```
$ sudo ./build/samples/sockex3                                                                             
[sudo] password for navarro:                                                                                                                                                                  
libbpf: loading ./build/samples/bpf/CMakeFiles/sockex3_kern.dir/sockex3_kern.c.o                                                                                                              
libbpf: elf: section(3) socket/3, size 1264, link 0, flags 6, type=1                                                                                                                          
libbpf: sec 'socket/3': found program 'bpf_func_PARSE_IP' at insn offset 0 (0 bytes), code size 158 insns (1264 bytes)
libbpf: elf: section(4) .relsocket/3, size 128, link 31, flags 0, type=9
libbpf: elf: section(5) socket/4, size 1360, link 0, flags 6, type=1
libbpf: sec 'socket/4': found program 'bpf_func_PARSE_IPV6' at insn offset 0 (0 bytes), code size 170 insns (1360 bytes)
libbpf: elf: section(6) .relsocket/4, size 112, link 31, flags 0, type=9
libbpf: elf: section(7) socket/1, size 256, link 0, flags 6, type=1
libbpf: sec 'socket/1': found program 'bpf_func_PARSE_VLAN' at insn offset 0 (0 bytes), code size 32 insns (256 bytes)
libbpf: elf: section(8) .relsocket/1, size 16, link 31, flags 0, type=9
libbpf: elf: section(9) socket/2, size 120, link 0, flags 6, type=1
libbpf: sec 'socket/2': found program 'bpf_func_PARSE_MPLS' at insn offset 0 (0 bytes), code size 15 insns (120 bytes)
libbpf: elf: section(10) .relsocket/2, size 16, link 31, flags 0, type=9
libbpf: elf: section(11) socket/0, size 32, link 0, flags 6, type=1
libbpf: sec 'socket/0': found program 'main_prog' at insn offset 0 (0 bytes), code size 4 insns (32 bytes)
libbpf: elf: section(12) license, size 4, link 0, flags 3, type=1
libbpf: license of ./build/samples/bpf/CMakeFiles/sockex3_kern.dir/sockex3_kern.c.o is GPL
libbpf: elf: section(13) .maps, size 96, link 0, flags 3, type=1
libbpf: elf: section(22) .BTF, size 4807, link 0, flags 0, type=1
libbpf: elf: section(24) .BTF.ext, size 2704, link 0, flags 0, type=1
libbpf: elf: section(31) .symtab, size 5904, link 1, flags 0, type=2
libbpf: looking for externs among 246 symbols...
libbpf: failed to find BTF for extern 'unlikely': -2
ERROR: opening BPF object file failed
```

I am trying to understand how/when this symbol is define. I found the symbol [here](https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf/blob/master/include/linux/compiler.h).
Why libbpf is not finding it? Am I missing anything? FYI, I removed the `uapi` from the kernel file ([sockex3_kern.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/samples/bpf/sockex3_kern.c)) and copied the dependencies (i.e. [bpf_legacy.h](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/tools/testing/selftests/bpf/bpf_legacy.h)) to my repository.

Another thing that I cant understand is why the sections (below) of the object file (out of the kernel tree) are different

```
31 .llvm_addrsig     00000012 0000000000000000 <--- Available in the object out of the tree
```

when comparing to the object file generated in the kernel tree.

Out-of-tree

```
$ llvm-objdump -h build/samples/bpf/CMakeFiles/sockex3_kern.dir/sockex3_kern.c.o 

build/samples/bpf/CMakeFiles/sockex3_kern.dir/sockex3_kern.c.o: file format elf64-bpf

Sections:
Idx Name              Size     VMA              Type
  0                   00000000 0000000000000000 
  1 .strtab           000002c2 0000000000000000 
  2 .text             00000000 0000000000000000 TEXT
  3 socket/3          000004d0 0000000000000000 TEXT
  4 .relsocket/3      00000070 0000000000000000 
  5 socket/4          00000550 0000000000000000 TEXT
  6 .relsocket/4      00000070 0000000000000000 
  7 socket/1          00000100 0000000000000000 TEXT
  8 .relsocket/1      00000010 0000000000000000 
  9 socket/2          00000078 0000000000000000 TEXT
 10 .relsocket/2      00000010 0000000000000000 
 11 socket/0          000000e8 0000000000000000 TEXT
 12 .relsocket/0      00000010 0000000000000000 
 13 license           00000004 0000000000000000 DATA
 14 .maps             00000060 0000000000000000 DATA
 15 .debug_loc        00000ef1 0000000000000000 
 16 .rel.debug_loc    00000370 0000000000000000 
 17 .debug_abbrev     000002b9 0000000000000000 
 18 .debug_info       00000f1b 0000000000000000 
 19 .rel.debug_info   000013c0 0000000000000000 
 20 .debug_ranges     000002e0 0000000000000000 
 21 .rel.debug_ranges 00000420 0000000000000000 
 22 .debug_str        000007c2 0000000000000000 
 23 .BTF              000012e1 0000000000000000 
 24 .rel.BTF          00000040 0000000000000000 
 25 .BTF.ext          00000ac0 0000000000000000 
 26 .rel.BTF.ext      00000a70 0000000000000000 
 27 .debug_frame      00000088 0000000000000000 
 28 .rel.debug_frame  000000a0 0000000000000000 
 29 .debug_line       0000049e 0000000000000000 
 30 .rel.debug_line   00000050 0000000000000000 
 31 .llvm_addrsig     00000012 0000000000000000 
 32 .symtab           00001788 0000000000000000
```

Kernel tree

```
$ llvm-objdump -h sockex3_kern.o 

sockex3_kern.o: file format elf64-bpf

Sections:
Idx Name              Size     VMA              Type
  0                   00000000 0000000000000000 
  1 .strtab           000002b1 0000000000000000 
  2 .text             00000000 0000000000000000 TEXT
  3 socket/3          000004d8 0000000000000000 TEXT
  4 .relsocket/3      00000070 0000000000000000 
  5 socket/4          00000558 0000000000000000 TEXT
  6 .relsocket/4      00000070 0000000000000000 
  7 socket/1          00000100 0000000000000000 TEXT
  8 .relsocket/1      00000010 0000000000000000 
  9 socket/2          00000078 0000000000000000 TEXT
 10 .relsocket/2      00000010 0000000000000000 
 11 socket/0          000000e8 0000000000000000 TEXT
 12 .relsocket/0      00000010 0000000000000000 
 13 license           00000004 0000000000000000 DATA
 14 .maps             00000060 0000000000000000 DATA
 15 .debug_loc        00000ef1 0000000000000000 
 16 .rel.debug_loc    00000370 0000000000000000 
 17 .debug_abbrev     0000029f 0000000000000000 
 18 .debug_info       00000d4b 0000000000000000 
 19 .rel.debug_info   000011b0 0000000000000000 
 20 .debug_ranges     000002e0 0000000000000000 
 21 .rel.debug_ranges 00000420 0000000000000000 
 22 .debug_str        0000067d 0000000000000000 
 23 .BTF              000012c2 0000000000000000 
 24 .rel.BTF          00000040 0000000000000000 
 25 .BTF.ext          00000ac0 0000000000000000 
 26 .rel.BTF.ext      00000a70 0000000000000000 
 27 .eh_frame         000000b0 0000000000000000 DATA
 28 .rel.eh_frame     00000050 0000000000000000 
 29 .debug_line       0000046b 0000000000000000 
 30 .rel.debug_line   00000050 0000000000000000 
 31 .symtab           00001500 0000000000000000
```

Thank you in advance!